# Data Frame Modification in R

Tags: r, dplyr, unique

the three lines of R code below show a vector a1,b1 and "c1" which is the unique of fields a1. I want to display a data frame of two columns where I should get every element of c1 displayed the number of times equal to the length of elements in "a1", in one column, and the corresponding ID "b1" of that letter in another column. Simply, say a data frame with column "y" in which say letter "a" from "c1" will be represented 6 times back to back(length of string a1), then "b" 6 times, then c and so on. Also corresponding to a in other column, "1" 6 times, then "2" 6 times and so on. Please help and thanks.

```
a1 = c("a","b","c","d","a","b")
b1 = c(1,2,3,4,1,2)
c1 = unique(a1)
```

**New Change**

```
a1 = c("a","b","b","d","c","e","f","a","b","c","d")
b1 = c(1,1,1,2,3,2,3,1,1,3,2)
c1 = unique(a1)
```

Comment: I have got through one part, rep(c1, each = length(a1)), gives me the appropriate column, please help me with assigning the correct index to every letter in the string.

Comment: Is this what you mean ? cbind(rep(c1, each = length(a1)),rep(b1, each = length(a1)))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This achieves what you ask I believe:

```
cbind(rep(c1, each = length(a1)),rep(b1, each = length(a1)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @user124123, but apologies, I have added a new tweak in the second part, can you help me with an issue, where multiple letters have same index, and then I want to assign them, thanks. I will surely accept your response if you help me there please.

Comment: any clues here?

Comment: Please, review your answer. `rep(c1, each = length(a1))` and `rep(b1, each = length(a1))` have different lengths of 24 and 36, resp., (for the first dataset) and a warning is issued.

Answer (score 0):

`a1` and `b1` have to be combined into one data.frame *before* the `unique()` function is applied. Otherwise, the vectors have different lengths.

```
DF <- data.frame(a1, b1)
unique(DF)[rep(1:nrow(unique(DF)), each = nrow(DF)), ]
```

For the first dataset

```
a1 = c("a","b","c","d","a","b")
b1 = c(1,2,3,4,1,2)
```

the result is:

> ```
>     a1 b1
> 1    a  1
> 1.1  a  1
> 1.2  a  1
> 1.3  a  1
> 1.4  a  1
> 1.5  a  1
> 2    b  2
> 2.1  b  2
> 2.2  b  2
> 2.3  b  2
> 2.4  b  2
> 2.5  b  2
> 3    c  3
> 3.1  c  3
> 3.2  c  3
> 3.3  c  3
> 3.4  c  3
> 3.5  c  3
> 4    d  4
> 4.1  d  4
> 4.2  d  4
> 4.3  d  4
> 4.4  d  4
> 4.5  d  4
> ```

consisting 24 rows (4 unique values in `a1` times 6 which is the length of `a1`)

Note that this different to [user124123's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47716620/3817004) which has 36 rows (`length(b1)` times `length(a1)` caused by `rep(b1, each = length(a1))`.

For the second dataset

```
a1 = c("a","b","b","d","c","e","f","a","b","c","d")
b1 = c(1,1,1,2,3,2,3,1,1,3,2)
```

the result consists of 66 rows (6 unique values times 11).
(Output omitted for brevity).