# How to Classify data frame Based on a Columns in R?

Tags: r, classification

I have a data frame and has columns like this:

```
gene    col1    col2    type
------------------------------
gene_1   a       b        1
gene_2   aa      bb       2
gene_3   a       b        1
gene_4   aa      bb       2
```

I want to find the column "type" using column "col2" and "col1". so I need a classification based on "col2" and "col1". how should I do this in R?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based. on the output, an option is to create group indices from columns 'col1', and 'col2'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(type = group_indices(., col1, col2))
#.   gene col1 col2 type
#1 gene_1    a    b    1
#2 gene_2   aa   bb    2
#3 gene_3    a    b    1
#4 gene_4   aa   bb    2
```

If there are multiple names, then one option is to convert the string column names to `sym`bols and then evaluate (`!!!`)

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(type = group_indices(., !!! rlang::syms(names(.)[2:3])))
```

---

Or in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, type := .GRP, .(col1, col2)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(gene = c("gene_1", "gene_2", "gene_3", "gene_4"
), col1 = c("a", "aa", "a", "aa"), col2 = c("b", "bb", "b", "bb"
), type = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works for 2 columns, what if I have 400 columns? how can I write the code without naming all columns?

Comment: @Mahshid. If your 400 columns are from 2 to 401th position, `rlang::syms(names(.)[2:401]`. make the changes. to the index accordingly